# How to re-use ImageDataGenerator fit params (e.g. featurewise_center, featurewise_std_normalization) in evaluation?

Tags: keras

I use ImageDataGenerator .fit() to normalize training data. But then there is no elegant way to perform .standardize() on real when I deploy the model (different running code then training).

I realize I can extract the normalization params, save them somewhere and then perform the normalization myself but then it would be easier to write it myself to begin with.

Is there a way to this in the current design?
Is there a way to do .standardize() long after the training code has completed?

Comment: I could not understand what you mean exactly. Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118955/2099607) work for you?

Comment: If you are actually working on a real problem-solution (rather then doing experimentation, self-learning or research), your production environment (where user data is sent to for inference) is likely very different then your training one. The production environment does not have `datagen` (the ImageDataGenerator instance) available, nor is it trivial to re-create it there. Then you need to carry the normalization parameters (and method?) there somehow (serialize them along with the model) and re-write `standardize` there. I would have expected the design to treat this concern somehow.

Comment: In short, the solution above will not work because it assumes `datagen` is still available in inference time...